# preg_match with repeated html content

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

I would like tu pull some data from an external website. The html string looks like this (*without spaces/lines breaks between the img tags*):

```
<img class="car-type231" src="/2f36b523259e9871bfade01983c9cc91.png" title="toyota"/>
<img class="car-type211" src="/0abc9b3ae3ba4bbcb6d3593fad6c1450.png" title="nissan"/>
<img class="car-type311" src="/4528e30bb510b4289121b4c70cb48ea3.png" title="bmw"/>
<img class="car-type332" src="/64575fee55553623896c7fd587a33ac3.png" title="mercedes"/>
<img class="car-type544" src="/a4f32dd95976d76704795c471c9a08b8.png" title="audi"/>
etc...
```

I want to pull every src path and create an array that would look like this:

```
$matches[0] = '/2f36b523259e9871bfade01983c9cc91.png';
$matches[1] = '/0abc9b3ae3ba4bbcb6d3593fad6c1450.png';
etc...
```

I tried using preg_match with this parameter: `'#src="(.*?)"#'` but it doesn't worked because it's returning all the html.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The pony he comes...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Use a parser such as DOMDocument:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
$l = $imgs->length;
$srcs = []; // Array() in earlier versions of PHP
for( $i=0; $i<$l; $i++) {
    $srcs[$i] = $imgs->item($i)->getAttribute("src");
}
```

Comment: I was going to answer with the pony but, you did it first! I do think too that you shouldn't be using regex to parse html

Answer (score 0):

You'll get a lot of grief for trying to pull this stuff out using RegEx instead of using a proper document/HTML parser, but I personally see no problem with using RegEx in this case because the HTML is so simple - and your goal is simple as well.

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('#src="(.*?)"#',$htmlstring,$matches);
print_r($matches[1]); //the array you want
```

Comment: You should also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Only this guy isn't trying to parse all of the complexities of HTML - he's trying to pull out all src="" attributes from a very repetitive piece of HTML that I assume is always going to be the same. There is nothing wrong with using the above solution.

Comment: The second comment on that question reflects my thoughts exactly - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1733489/755900